# Can't access my SQL Server without SQL Engine

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two computers. One is running SQL Server, and I can access the server using SQL authentication from the 2nd PC using SSMS.

I have created a C# Windows Forms application that connects to the database. However, I couldn't access my server from the application.

I disabled the firewall, allowed remote control, and allowed mixed mode authentication. I also forwarded required ports to my IP in my router settings.

I tried both these connecting strings, but they didn't help:

```
"Persist Security Info = False; User ID = gues; Password=gues;Initial Catalog = CoronaNurse; Server=" + server;

"Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=CoronaNurse;Integrated Security=false;UID=gues;Password=gues";
```

(server is a string that have IP of my server)
(gues is a login in my Server)

The weird thing is when I login as `gues` in SSMS from my 2nd computer I can access the server in the first computer.

The question is, how do I access my server from a computer that doesn't have SSMS or any specific Login?

I need my application to be able to connect to my server without anything else installed, but I can't find where my problem is.

---

Adding from comments:

Im using the connecting to get a con string from my DB depends on the table i get with my `gue.login` function SqlDataAdapter

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from gue.login('" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "', '" + server + "')", conn); 
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
adapter.Fill(ds); 
string connection; 
connection = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Comment: Use a different tool. `sqlcmd`, Powershell (and the `sqlserver` module), ADS, or install SSMS, what ever you like. SSMS isn't the *only* tool to access SQL Server, it's one of 10's of methods.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Can't I just connect to my server using connecting strings in my C# app code?
I don't need the client to install anything besides my application
It is actually a project to my college so I can't tell the doctor to get SSMS or create login or anything, it is not logical tho..

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: What error are you receiving back from C# when it attempts to open the connection? I agree that its likely not firewall since you have already corrected that and confirmed that you can connect over SMSS (it's all the same port, I believe). I also agree that you don't need a client installed on the computer and this is all doable with C#. What you are attempting is perfectly normal, it's just that you are hitting some error in the connection.

Comment: Im using the connecting to get a con string from my DB depends on the table i get with my gue.login function
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from gue.login('" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "', '" + server + "')", conn);
                SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                string connection;
                connection = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

Comment: If I disable my SQL Instance service in my 2nd PC 
I get network error
if I enable it I can access, but if I disable "gues" login in my 2nd computer Server
I can't access my server
it is a bit complicated and im confused excuse me

Comment: There are two areas in databases that are too important to do wrong, even for learning/proof of concept code. One of those is SQL injection. The other is password storage. The sample code in the comment is wrong for both. Before doing anything else, go lookup how to use parameterized queries and bcrypt. It would be better to NOT have username/password on this application at all than to continue with the incorrect password storage you're using now.

Comment: I've added your comment into an edit on your post. Any followup information you can add such as the error test, etc, please edit the post in a similar fashion.

Comment: Also... the SQL syntax is wrong (no `WHERE` keyword). Are you maybe connecting correctly, and then running bad SQL? It would help us know for sure if you **posted the actual exception message.**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you haven't posted up all of your code, you don't appear to be controlling your SQL connection and I would strongly suggest that you use a parameterised call to protect against SQL injection from using direct text entry field values e.g.:

```
var dataset = new DataSet();

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("GetAll", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly open the connection if you're using the `Fill()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is wrong, and the connection strings look a little off. You might also need an **instance name** as part of the server. For example, instead of just `localhost` or `192.168.0.20`, you might need `localhost\SQLExpress` or `192.168.0.20\.`.

One way you can find the connection string for sure is to use Visual Studio instead of SSMS to connect to the database. The Visual Studio Database Tools has a similar connection window as SSMS, and you can use it to [*show you the actual connection string it used.*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ba6b1757-301c-4545-98e4-69a81b33e876/find-connection-string-used-by-sql-server-management-studio?forum=sqldataaccess)

When you've figured that out, try something more like this:

```
var connString = $"Server={server};Database=CoronaNurse;User Id=gues;Password=gues";

var sql = "select * from gue.login WHERE username = @username AND pHash = @pHash";
var ds = new DataSet();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pHash", SqlDbType.Char, 60).Value = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(textBox2.Text.Trim());
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    var connection = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Items[0].ToString();
}
```

Note the use of both parameterized queries and BCrypt (you can add BCrypt via NuGet). There are a few things in database development that are too important to do wrong, *even for proof-of-concept and learning projects.* One of these is SQL Injection. Another is password handling. What I posted *still isn't quite right for password handling* (you should instead retrieve the stored hash and use the `Verify()` method), but it's close enough to set you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has told me that I can't access my online SQL Server DB from a client PC that doesn't have a Local DB.
I guess that explains my problem perfectly!
I never knew that, in my case, that is my problem right?

Comment: So are you using LocalDB or not? LocalDB doesn't have an option for remote connections, but you said you enabled it? What actual error message are you getting?

Comment: I have installed SSMS and created a database on my machine with it
and then i configured it to work with remote and stuff like this
and then i sent my exe application to another machine that have SSMS too
and I used a connecting string with the IP of my first machine to access my DB

I'm beginner student so I'm not sure if my DB in that case called LocalDB I guess it is not,
@Charlieface